# Word to express nervous anticipation

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a word or phrase that expresses the feeling of nervous anticipation as you wait for the result of something, whose outcome you cannot control and could be either good or bad?

Comment: I personally think that "nervous anticipation" itself works quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**anxiety**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anxiety?s=t

It's a very precise word denoting exactly what you describe.

**anxious**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anxious?s=t

This one is very often misused. People think it's synonymous with "eager," which is kind of silly. It is not.

Answer (score 3):

**I am like a cat on hot bricks**.

Also, "like a cat on a hot tin roof".

> Definition: Restless or skittish, unable to
>   remain still.
>
> Example: *Nervous about the lecture he had to give, David
>   was like a cat on hot bricks*.

Other idioms:

- to wait on tenterhooks (in a state of uneasy suspense or painful anxiety)
- to sit on a hot rock
- to be on pins and needles